# Is there a way to display data from a private google spreadsheet as a chart on a website?

Tags: javascript, web, google-apps-script, spreadsheet, html

I am doing a project for my school. I have logged in the number of visitors who come to the school using a car, a bike, a bicycle or some other form of transport on a google spreadsheet. I want to be able to display all the data in the form of charts on my school website in order to keep track of the CO2 emissions caused by people to come to school daily.
I read about the google spreadsheet api but can't understand how to get data from the spreadsheet without making it public. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to code this in apps script. Google sheets natively supports publishing charts.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78052

Depending on how you published the chart, its a different process to update the chart as the data changes.
If you used "publish to the web", simply republish, or modify the URL to remove the range (with some caveats, see this help topic on ways to do it. Its an old post and the new sheets publish url may be different or allow open ranges (like A1:C). https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/docs/how-do-i/ZRpghByKHNM

If you publish the chart inside a doc or presentation, see http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.pe/2016/05/embed-charts-from-google-sheets-in.html which is a more streamlined way to update the chart, but requires an intermediate doc/slide.

Comment: Will the chart get updated each time a new entry is made in the sheet?

Comment: Your solution is just so simple. I don't have to do anything. Thanks. It's great!

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely, write code in Google app script to get required data from spreadsheet, **deploy** your script (**anyone even anonymous** option), change version of script each time when you are changing code and deploy again.

Get URL of deployed app script, do **ajax call** to that url from your javascript code (in your web application) and get required data and use it to show chart using any chart plugin from jquery.

Comment: I tried google app script, works really well. Can I return data in JSON format using it?

Comment: JSON.stringify(data);

Comment: What is the difference in deploying as a web app and deploying as an API executable? Thanks.

Comment: this answer is overkill, google sheets natively support publishing and updating charts.

Comment: This solution may work well when you wan to display the data in a custom chart and not like the google charts.